# Output Displayed Prior to User Requested Input

Tags: c

Why does the following program show an answer to a non-user defined total value entered prior to entering the input?  How would the code be written to ask for the input of the money prior to showing the output?  Current compiler output style show below:

```
TOTAL VALUE ENTERED: $  0.32
1 quarters
0 dimes
1 nickels
2 pennies

Enter the amount of money you would like calculate change for:
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(float, int *, int*, int*, int*); /*chreate change function*/

int main(void)
{
    float totalVal; /*establish variables and their data types*/
    int quar, dime, nick, pen;

    /*run through 1 with given totalVal*/
    {
        totalVal = 1.88;

        change(totalVal, &quar, &dime, &nick, &pen); /*call function*/

        printf("TOTAL VALUE ENTERED: $%6.2f", totalVal); /*display results*/
        printf("\n%d quarters", quar);
        printf("\n%d dimes", dime);
        printf("\n%d nickels", nick);
        printf("\n%d pennies", pen);
    }

    /*run through 2 with given totalVal*/
    {
        totalVal = 0.32;

        change(totalVal, &quar, &dime, &nick, &pen); /*call function*/

        printf("\nTOTAL VALUE ENTERED: $%6.2f", totalVal); /*display results*/
        printf("\n%d quarters", quar);
        printf("\n%d dimes", dime);
        printf("\n%d nickels", nick);
        printf("\n%d pennies", pen);
    }
    /*run through 3 with user entry for totalVal*/
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter the amount of money desired to calculate change for: \n");
        scanf("%f", &totalVal); /*call for user entry*/

        change(totalVal, &quar, &dime, &nick, &pen); /*call function*/

        printf("\nTOTAL VALUE ENTERED: $%6.2f", totalVal); /*display results*/
        printf("\n%d quarters", quar);
        printf("\n%d dimes", dime);
        printf("\n%d nickels", nick);
        printf("\n%d pennies", pen);
    }
}

void change(float totalVal, int *q, int *d, int *n, int *p) /*passes variables through 
   change calculations then back to their original addresses*/
{
    if ( totalVal >= 0.250 )
        *q = (totalVal/0.250);

    if( totalVal >= 0.100 )
        *d = (totalVal - (*q * 0.250))/0.100;

    if( totalVal >= 0.050 )
        *n = (totalVal - (*q * 0.250) - (*d * 0.100))/0.050;

    if( totalVal >= 0.010 )
        *p = (totalVal - (*q * 0.250) - (*d * 0.100) - (*n * 0.050))/0.010+.005;

    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem; this calls `change` twice before asking for input, and prints the results for each call.

Comment: Also puzzling are the use of `{}` in `main`.

Comment: instructions are executed top to bottom, staring in `main`. Get rid of the `totalValue = ...` lines and move the `scanf` call before the first call to `change` if you want to ask the user for the amount to make change for.

Comment: Having compiled and run your code, it does exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Better to convert from [fractional] dollars and work in cents. See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425103/i-am-doing-the-cs50-pset-1-cash-and-whenever-i-am-running-this-code-the-termina/72425386#72425386